# В Python выбрать слева элемент, ближайший по значению?

Tags: python, list, сравнение

У меня два списка: малый на 10 элементов и большой на 20. Часть элементов совпадает (через один).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь задача выбирать точки в левом, малом, списке. Причем так:

1. если значения элементов совпадают - берем из малого списка элементы от совпадающего значения вниз (размер окна `order` задается пользователем, например, 3).
2. если при сравнении значения `x_i` и `x_j` не совпадают, то из ряда значений `x_i` выбираем ближайшее к `x_j` слева (в нашем случае - сверху) значение `x_i` и уже от него отсчитываем вниз заданное окно.

> например, для значения x_j = 0.157 ближайшее слева значение x_i = 0; аналогично: для значения x_j = 0.471 ближайшее слева значение x_i = 0.314

Как мне выбрать элемент в инструкции `else`?

Код:

```
x_i_list = [(0.1*np.pi*i) for i in range(0, 11)]
x_j_list = [(0.05*np.pi*j) for j in range(0, 21)]
order = 3
for point_elem_j in x_j_list:
    for point_elem_i in x_i_list:
        # если значения совпадают:
        if x_j_list[point_elem_j] == x_i_list[point_elem_i]:
            x_0 = x_i_list[point_elem_i]
        else:
            # если значения не совпадают: как выбрать ближайшее слева в ряду x_i?  
            ...
        # задаем правую границу окна, исходя из величины order: 
        x_elem_index = x_i_list[point_elem_i+order-1]
```

Comment: Списки ведь сортированные? Не надо тогда таким топорным способом искать

Comment: @MBo, сорри: нетопорным не придумал ))

Comment: Привёл псевдокод, как можно параллельно двигаться по спискам

Comment: @MBo, благодарю - сейчас смотрю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот смотрите - у вас два ряда точек последовательно лежат вдоль оси, многие точки совпадают. Нужно двигаться по обоим одновременно с помощью двух индексов. Какой элемент меньше - тот индекс увеличивать. Так получается линейное время.

```
ia = 0
ib = 0
while ia < a_len and ib < b_len:
  if a[ia] < b[ib]:
       делаем что-то 
       ia += 1
  elif a[ia] > b[ib]:
       делаем что-то  другое
       ib += 1
  else:
       делаем третье для случая равенства
       ia += 1
       ib += 1   
 # в одном из списков могут остаться необработанные элементы
 while ia < a_len:
    делаем что-то с остатком а
    ia +=1 
 while ib < b_len:
    делаем что-то с остатком b 
    ib +=1
```